How to query Gaia stars which are inside a given contour on the sky?
I am a student and started looking at Gaia data. My first exercise was to query the Gaia star catalogue inside a given (ra, dec) contour on the sky. To do this, I tried using ADQL in Python along with astroquery. I was able to query Gaia's stellar catalogue in a given circular region on the sky centred on a given (ra, dec). There is a Polygon option ADQL that lets the user query Gaia inside a given polygon given its vertices. But it only supports polygons with vertices ~20. My contour has around 1000 vertices, and I wanted to ask if there is a way to query the data within contours with a large number of vertices.
Thanks a lot for the suggestions in advance!
